# PHP parameter / Nested folder / CMS

Tags: php, seo, content-management-system, nested

Say I have a website birdsovertheworld.com/ and I want to add some content in form of the birds I know about. I (as far as I know) can do either

a) birdsovertheworld.com/bird/hummingbird/

or

b) birdsovertheworld.com/bird/show.php?bird=hummingbird

Going with a) seems very silly as it'd require me to manually create a folder + an index file for each bird.

Going with b) on the other hand would (again, as far as I'm concerned) hurt SEO and readability.

The CMS I'm familiar with won't work for my purpose (WordPress, Joomla) + I would in this particular situation rather not use one.

My question is:
- how can I achieve a URL easily readable for the user and the search engine *without* creating the folders and index files manually and *without* going with example b?

Thanks

Comment: are you using apache?

Comment: Yeah, currently I am :-o?

Answer (score 0):

a) is actually a valid option.  We do it at work by forcing Apache to read certain scripts as PHP even if they don't have file extensions.

So, "bird" is a PHP script that reads the called URL and includes/generates content that varies according to the content of the url string:

```
$called = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$parts = explode("/",$called);
$birdname = $parts[1];
switch($birdname) { // or whatever logic.
```

The Apache configuration uses ForceType application/x-httpd-php5.

Answer (score 0):

If you look, for example, into WordPress `.htaccess` file, you would see something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

This tells Apache to redirect any non-existent file or folder that is being accessed by the browser, to `index.php`.

Then, on the PHP side, you get the original requested url inside the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` variable.

Finally, you can use `explode(...)` to access the path that was requested:

```
$path = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
switch($path[1]){
    case 'bird':
        //do your things
        break;
    default:
        //404
}
```

Remember that you have to properly handle `404 errors`, since Apache won't know if that particular bird exists or not.